# How do I use mpl_connect to highlight points different from the one selected?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

I have a simple time series `(x, y, t)`.  I have plotted all the points `(x,y)` on a two-dimensional scatter plot using matplotlib and am able to access the time value for each point by making `"t"` a label and using `mplcursors` `connect`:

```
labels = data.index
points = plt.scatter(data['Column1'], data['Column2'], color=color)
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(points, hover=2)
cursor.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(labels[sel.index]))
```

I am looking for a way that upon selection of a point, that point as well as the **next** point in the time series will be highlighted, so the viewer can see where the series is going.   I can always put the coordinates of the following point in as a label, but I would like the visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a small circle, e.g. via `plt.scatter` at the position of the next point.  Appending it to `sel.extras` takes care of removing it as soon as the current highlight is removed.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mplcursors

def annotation_func(sel):
    if sel.index < len(data) - 1:
        x0, y0 = data.iloc[sel.index][['Column1', 'Column2']]
        x1, y1 = data.iloc[sel.index + 1][['Column1', 'Column2']]
        circle = plt.scatter(x1, y1, s=100, fc='none', ec='red', lw=2)
        line, = plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], c='red', lw=1, ls=':')
        sel.extras.append(circle)
        sel.extras.append(line)
    sel.annotation.set_text(data.index[sel.index])

data = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': np.arange(30),
                     'Column2': np.random.randn(30).cumsum()},
                    index=[f'P{i}' for i in range(30)])

points = plt.scatter(data['Column1'], data['Column2'], color='turquoise')
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(points, hover=2)
cursor.connect("add", annotation_func)
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors add extra circle and line]